# get all possible combinations that add up to 1 using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to create a list of lists with 3 elements (0.05 increments) that add up to 1, i.e., [[0,0,1],[0,0.05,0.95],[0,0.1,0.9],[0,0.15,0.85]...[0.95,0.05,0],[1,0,0]].

Here's the code I wrote:

```
import itertools.product
possible_contributions = [i/100 for i in range(0,101,5)]
all_model_combs = itertools.product(possible_contributions, repeat=3)
usable_list = [comb for comb in all_model_combs if sum(comb)==1]
```

The `usable_list` has a length of 226. I notice that I am missing several possible combinations in my `usable_list`, for example, [0.2,0.7,0.2], [0.3,0.35,0.35],[0.3,0.6,0.1]...and I do not find a pattern among the missing. I find it hard to troubleshoot `itertools.product`, and I was wondering what I am missing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation of float arithmetics.  Use math.isclose() and set a tolerance for acceptable proximity rather than equality to 1:

```
import itertools
import math
possible_contributions = [i/100 for i in range(0,101,5)]
all_model_combs = itertools.product(possible_contributions, repeat=3)
usable_list = [comb for comb in all_model_combs if math.isclose(sum(comb),1, rel_tol=1e-06)]

print(len(usable_list)) #231
```

Comment: This is not a limitation of *python* this is a limitation of binary floating point in general

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true!

Answer (score 1):

It's a rounding error, if you try it with integers it works:

```
import itertools
possible_contributions = [i for i in range(0,101,5)]
all_model_combs = itertools.product(possible_contributions, repeat=3)
usable_list = [comb for comb in all_model_combs if sum(comb)==100]
(20, 60, 20) in usable_list
(30, 35, 35) in usable_list
(30, 60, 10) in usable_list
```

But `30/100 + 35/100 + 35/100 != 100/100`

I suggest you

- divide by 100 only at the end or
- give your sum comparison more room e.g. `abs(sum(comb) - 1) < 0.0001`